# Display map object from SQL database in MapInfo with read only access to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapinfo

I can connect MapInfo to a SQL database using a select statement to display the contents of a table in the SQL database. However, the table is not mapable and I only have read access to the database therefore cannot make it mapable.
Is there any way I can display the data from the SQL database stored in a Geometry column in MapInfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the MapInfo metadata tables in that database, or you have to manually copy the data into some other database or file.